# C# OpenCV FAST Feature Detection

Tags: c#, opencv, feature-detection

I've been unable to find a tutorial on how to implement the FAST Feature detection algorithms with tracking using C# with openCV, and I can't figure it out from the documentation. How can I implement FAST feature detection and specifically feature matching (similar to the SURF feature tracking example).

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

I am working on the same topic, maybe this code is usefull to you:

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/tests/cv/src/fast.cpp?rev=2300

I still cannot compile my code due to a link error.

Comment: Link error usually are because you import the libraries incorrectly. If you are using VS, check the linker options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx . I prefer Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

As Jav_Rock has pointed out you can still build a wrapper around the function or code he has pasted, but one other option would be to use [EMGU Opencv](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php?title=Special%3aSearch&search=FAST%20features&go=Go) which happens to be a complete wrapper in C# for OpenCV. Should help you a lot and avoid trouble of writing a wrapper, but you will still need to port the code to C#